# red5: how can i get current IConnection?

Tags: red5

under the function appConnect() i added several attributes to the IConnection class of the current connected user.

i want to fetch that information in other functions, how do i get the IConnection of the current connection while i'm not in appConnect() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in each function the following command will provide the IConnection of the current connection:

IConnection conn = Red5.getConnectionLocal();

Answer (score 0):

In your ApplicationAdapter you can also add the connection as the first parameter like so:

```
public boolean isFoo(String foo)
```

becomes

```
public boolean isFoo(IConnection conn, String foo)
```